# Converting "section" into "\section" to pass to the titleformat command

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

The `\titleformat` command of the `titlesec` package is invoked in the following way:

```
\titleformat{\section}{<a few formatting options>}
\titleformat{\subsection}{<a few formatting options>}
```

I'm writing a small package to automate some formatting, including the formatting of section titles, and `titlesec` is one of the packages I'm "wrapping around". The problem is that I'd like my code to be written in the following form

```
\sectionfamily{section}{uppercase}
\sectionfamily{subsection}{italic}
```

Here `\sectionfamily` is my custom command that, as part of its execution, will eventually call `\titleformat`. Suppose, for the sake of the question, that it is defined like:

```
\newcommand{\sectionfamily}[2]{   
    \titleformat{\#1}{\itshape}{\thesection}{0pt}{}[]
}
```

As you see, I'm trying to convert `\sectionfamily{section}{...}` to `\titleformat{\section}{...}`, but the way I define it here doesn't work. I've tried many combinations of `\expandafter`, `\csname` and so on, but couldn't get any of those combinations to work either. Making an alias command and passing the alias also failed.

Does anyone know a way that the `section` can be converted into `\section` and made to work?

---

Note: the command `\titleformat{\section}{\itshape}{\thesection}{0pt}{}[]` works, and can be used to test things out. The full MWE (or minimal not working example!!) is

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\begin{document}

\section{How does this look?}

\newcommand{\sectionfamily}[2]{   
   \titleformat{\#1}{\itshape}{\thesection}{0pt}{}[]
}
\sectionfamily{section}{italic}
%What I want to run:
%\titleformat{\section}{\itshape}{\thesection}{0pt}{}[]
\section{How does this look?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should take a look at `expl3`.

Comment: What is the advantage over using `\titleformat*{\section}{\itshape}`? (This is even shorter than your command...)  And what happens when you want a section style that is `\sffamily\bfseries\itshape` or something with more than one 'quality'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There must be two `\expandafter` statements. The first to generate the command sequence and then for the `\titleformat` to expand in the internal setup (I've not looked into the package, however)

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec} 


\newcommand{\sectionfamily}[2]{%   
  \expandafter\titleformat\expandafter{\csname #1\endcsname}{\itshape}{\csname the#1\endcsname~}{0pt}{}[]
}


\sectionfamily{section}{italic}


\sectionfamily{subsection}{italic}


\begin{document}

\section{How does this look?}

%\newcommand{\sectionfamily}[2]{   
%   \titleformat{\#1}{\itshape}{\thesection}{0pt}{}[]
%}

%What I want to run:
%\titleformat{\section}{\itshape}{\thesection~}{0pt}{}[]
\section{How does this look?}

\subsection{Happy?}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will return to this later on

Comment: Could you please also provide the version of `\titleformat` using `numberless`? I can't find any syntax working with `\csname #1\endcsname`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use `expl3` (loaded by `xparse`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sectionfamily}{mm}
 {
  \fennell_section_family:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \fennell_section_family:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_fennell_section_font_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l_fennell_section_format_tl
  \str_case:nn { #2 }
   {
    { italic } { \tl_set:Nn \l_fennell_section_font_tl { \itshape } }
    { uppercase } { \tl_set:Nn \l_fennell_section_format_tl { \MakeUppercase } }
   }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \titleformat
     { \exp_not:c { #1 } }
     { \exp_not:V \l_fennell_section_font_tl }
     { \exp_not:c { the#1 } }
     { 1em }
     { \exp_not:V \l_fennell_section_format_tl }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sectionfamily{section}{uppercase}
\sectionfamily{subsection}{italic}

\begin{document}

\section{How does this look?}

\subsection{How does this look?}

\end{document}
```

You can add other keywords based on the examples given. I don't think you gain too much with this “automation”, though.

[image]