# Arguments transmission in \titleformat of titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I want make my own style of titles(`section/subsection... etc.`) by the package `titlesec`. The title name is specified by a macro. But it fails to pass compile. This do is a problem also for the other arguments of `\titleformat`. Why?
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\titlename{section}
\titleformat{\csname \titlename\endcsname}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{red}}{\the\titlename}{1em}{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that things need to get expanded in a different order. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239555/121799 for an example how that may be done.

Comment: What are you trying to obtain, exactly?

Comment: To define my style of title section, or subsection...etc. For example, `\settitle{name=section, format=...,label=..., ...}`.

Comment: Can you instead present what the desired format for `\settitle` is, with the correspondence between keys and arguments for `\titleformat`?

Comment: @egreg As it's hard to remember the meaning of every argument in `\titleformat` and `\titlespacing`, I decided to give names to all these args , that is to say, `\settitle{name=section, format=...,label=..., left=..., before title text=...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a key-value system for `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l__lyl_titlesec_main_clist

\keys_define:nn { lyl/titlesec }
 {
  name       .code:n   = \clist_put_right:Nx \l__lyl_titlesec_main_clist
                          { name = \exp_not:c {#1} },
  page       .code:n   = \clist_put_right:Nn \l__lyl_titlesec_main_clist
                          { page = #1 },
  numberless .code:n   = \clist_put_right:Nn \l__lyl_titlesec_main_clist
                          { numberless },
  shape      .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_titlesec_shape_tl,
  format     .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_titlesec_format_tl,
  label      .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_titlesec_label_tl,
  sep        .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_titlesec_sep_tl,
  before     .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_titlesec_before_tl,
  after      .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_titlesec_after_tl,
  unknown    .code:n   = \keys_set:nn { lyl/titlesec } { name = #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\lyltitleformat}{m}
 {
  % start afresh
  \clist_clear:N \l__lyl_titlesec_main_clist
  \keys_set:nn { lyl/titlesec }
   {
    shape = hang, format = , label = , sep = 0pt, before = , after = ,
   }
  % set the keys
  \keys_set:nn { lyl/titlesec } { #1 }
  % define the format
  \lyl_titlesec_set:VVVVVVV
   \l__lyl_titlesec_main_clist
   \l__lyl_titlesec_shape_tl
   \l__lyl_titlesec_format_tl
   \l__lyl_titlesec_label_tl
   \l__lyl_titlesec_sep_tl
   \l__lyl_titlesec_before_tl
   \l__lyl_titlesec_after_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lyl_titlesec_set:nnnnnnn
 {
  \titleformat{#1}[#2]{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[#7]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \lyl_titlesec_set:nnnnnnn { VVVVVVV }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\lyltitleformat{
  name = section,
  numberless,
  shape = hang,
  format = \large\bfseries,
  before = \MakeUppercase,
}
\lyltitleformat{
  name = section,
  shape = hang,
  format = \large\itshape,
  label = \thesection,
  sep = 1em,
  before = \adddashes,
}
\lyltitleformat{
  subsection,
  shape=runin,
  format=\scshape,
  label=(\thesubsection)~,
}

\newcommand{\adddashes}[1]{---#1---}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

abc def

\section{First}

abc def

\subsection{Xyz}

abc def

\end{document}
```

The level (or name) can be given either as value to `name` or without qualification. If you use the `explicit` option, you can use `#1` in the value for `before`.

There are two default values: `hang` for `shape` and `0pt` for `sep`.